# unable to switch to nvidia

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I installed nvidia driver using:`sudo apt-get nvidia-current`. After setting in Nvidia panel and reboot, the VGA in use remains the Intel.

And `lspci -vnnn | perl -lne 'print if /^\d+\:.+(\[\S+\:\S+\])/' | grep VGA`
 says:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0416] (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GK107M [GeForce GT 755M] [10de:0fcd] (rev ff) (prog-if ff)
```

How can I switch to NVidia?
By the way, when I exit full screen it freezes..

Answer (score 0):

Remove the currently installed drivers and install the latest stable drivers supporting GT 755M.

Open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
sudo reboot
```

After restart of the system ...

Open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352 nvidia-prime
sudo reboot
```

You can switch between the graphics with NVIDIA X Server Settings from the tab PRIME Profiles.

Comment: Still not work. Every time I change the setting (Intel or NVidia) the file .nvidia-setting-rc remain unchanged (except for last change date).